# Python / Pandas: Renaming several column names in DataFrame based on condition/index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename

I'm quite new to Python and Pandas. Tried so far to find an answer on the forum, but wuthout success.

My problem is the following:

- I import a dataframe from excel, with 2 columns containing parameter descriptions (strings), variable amount of columns with **weekly data** (4 to 5 depending on the number of weeks in a month; 01.mm.yyyy to (say) 28.mm.yyyy) as well as columns with **monthly data** (01.mm.yyyy)
- I need to rename **first 2 characters** of the **monthly data** (thus, starting as of column 6 or 7) column name string from 01 to (say) 25

E.g.:

| Col1 | Col2 | Wk 1- Wk 4 | 01.01.2021 | 01.02.2021 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2222 | .......... | .......... | .......... | ... |

I'd like to get the following:

| Col1 | Col2 | Wk 1- Wk 4 | 25.01.2021 | 25.02.2021 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2222 | .......... | .......... | .......... | ... |

I tried to get it solved through adressing the column index range with **df.columns**, following the code:

```
df.columns[m3_idx:] = df.columns[m3_idx:].str.replace("^01", "25")
```

where `m3_idx` is the index of the column, where the renaming should start. But I get a TypeError:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Index does not support mutable operations
```

How can I address the column indexes in order to specify the range of the columns, where the headers are to be changed?

**EDIT**: The idea is to change headers of only slice of the column range, as some of the "weekly data" columns before the monthly ones may start with the same string "01", which is not to be changed

Comment: You can try `df.columns = df.columns[:m3_idx].tolist() + df.columns[m3_idx:].str.replace('^01', '25').tolist()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: Tried right now, still getting the same error. It seems, that df.columns cannot accept a part of the column range as a slice to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> Index does not support mutable operations
> ```

This error is due to the left hand side of the assignment `df.columns[m3_idx:] = ...` (the right hand side works) - we can't assign to the slice. So, to make this work, we can construct the whole column index and assign to `df.columns`:

```
df.columns = pd.Index.union(df.columns[:m3_idx],
                            df.columns[m3_idx:].str.replace("^01", "25", regex=True),
                            sort=False)
```

Comment: AWESOME! It works! Thanks a lot! Just out of curiosity - what does the regex param means?

Comment: I noticed a `FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.` The `regex=True` assures that `"^01"` will continue to be interpreted as a regex when this change will happen.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to rename **first 2 characters** of the column name string from 01 to (say) 25

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x[:2].replace("01", "25")+x[2:], axis="columns")
```

(the x above is set to each name of the "columns" axis; the name is changed to the resulting value).

Here's a variant which replaces only names from the `m3_idx`th column on:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x, idx=iter(range(df.columns.size)):
                        x if next(idx) < m3_idx else x[:2].replace("01", "25")+x[2:],
          inplace=True)
```

Comment: It seems to work - but unfortunately, if some of the column headers before the monthly range contain 01 - they also get replaced. Therefore, I was trying to get hold of a slice of the columns, but not all of them.

Comment: When you say _contain 01_ you mean _start with 01_, right? - I'll soon have another answer.

Comment: yes, indeed. If e.g. the week of month of April would be 01.04.2021, the code above will also replace this one to 25. Thus, the weeks would go as follows: 25.04.2021, 08.04.2021, 15.05.2021.

Comment: Just for completeness, I added a variant with `rename()`.

Comment: Amazing - now I have two variants to choose from :)